# Compile Equinox 3.8.2 Project with java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, osgi, equinox

I need to create a gradle buildsystem for multiple OSGi Projects using Equinox 3.8.2. We use Java 7.

But now my Gradle script failes when compiling projects using the ServiceTracker:

```
Activator.java:11: error: type ServiceTracker does not take parameters
private static ServiceTracker<org.osgi.service.log.LogService, Object> logTracker = null;
```

I already found [this](http://blog.osgi.org/2012/10/43-companion-code-for-java-7.html) blog post.

But somehow eclipse succeedes when building the project manually using the same osgi 3.8.2 library.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse compiles using the Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ). Unlike javac 7, it is happy to use the generic signature information in the `-target jsr14` class files in the OSGi 4.3.0 jars. javac 7 made the explicit choice to ignore generic information in `-target jsr14` class file which is why you get that error. If you want to compiler with javac 7, you will need to use the OSGi 4.3.1 libraries which have been compiled `-target 1.5`.